# The Three ROME Object Models Design Pattern

Tags: design-patterns, rome

I have been reading about the three ROME object models which goes like this

```
SyndFeed(Model) <-- conversion --> RSS(Wire Feed Model)
SyndFeed(Model) <-- conversion --> Atom(Wire Feed Model)
```

I came to the conclusion that this model wouldn't actually meet my application needs but I still like this pattern however I can't figure out which design pattern this is!

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me like it could be a protocol style variation of the [`Adapter`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern) pattern.